# How would you develop efficient algorithm for this problem

Tags: math, statistics, computer-science

It's a flipping coin game. You put some amount of money and if the coin you flipped is Heads you earn double of amount what u put if its Tails you lose all

What would be the best strategy to not get bankrupt and maximize earnings?

You can flip as many times as you want and the coin is unbiased

Comment: Unclear wording. If I start with 10 and bet 1, and get Heads, do I then have 11 or 12?

Answer (score 0):

There is no strategy that can maximize your earning in the **unbiased coin case**.

Let us assume that at every head, you get earn **G** amount and at every tail, you lose **L** amount.

Let the probability of head in any trial is **P** and that of tail is **Q**.

Now, the expected value of your earning in a single trial can be given as:

> E = [PG + Q(-L)]
>
> E = (PG - QL)

Since, according to your question, G = L and P = Q. Therefore:

> E = PG - PG = 0

This means that even in a single trial your expected earning is zero.

However, if your **coin is biased** or your **earnings are not equal**, more precisely if **G > L** or **P > Q** then if you keep on playing long enough you can maximize earning.

I believe I watched one numberphile video long back regarding this kind of problem. You can try to search for it and get more insight of the problem.